# Rolling Back a Config w/ Adagios and Git

Tags: git, nagios

Bit of a newbie with Git and Adagios, and I changed a config file using the okconfig, and it broke the configuration.

```
"Executing nagios verify"
Nagios Core 3.5.1

Reading configuration data...
Read main config file okay...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/objects/contacts.cfg'...
```

It runs fine for about 15 more lines til

```
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/okconfig/hosts/default/HQ-PhoneServer-        host.cfg'...
Warning: Duplicate definition found for host 'HQ-PhoneServer' (config file   '/etc/nagios/okconfig/hosts/default/HQ-PhoneServer-host.cfg', starting on line 3)
Error: Could not add object property in file '/etc/nagios/okconfig/hosts/default/HQ-   PhoneServer-host.cfg' on line 7.
```

Error processing object config files!

Should I just jump into shell and edit the lines and start over or is it better to roll back.

It's a pretty barebones system that I had just recently added Adagios to, but I'm pretty new to working with Nagios, and got my core system setup already with it and vim.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you have 2 duplicate entries. It would appear that you have extra config files somehow from your process. I don't use Git or OkConfig so i cant comment on their involvment.

You can use:

```
cd /etc/nagios/okconfig/hosts
grep -ri "servernamehere" .
```

to locate where the duplicate is so that you can remove it. That is assuming all your host definitions are located in that folder or subfolder therein. R for recursive and i for case insensitive.

Both errors are about the same config file so once you find the offending entry you should be able to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it resolved by manually editing and commenting out the misconfigured files.